# packaging a nodejs c++ shared lib

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, webpack

I made a nodejs shared library and now I want to package it in order to deploy it.  I would like being  able to use it with angular 2 application packaged thanks to webpack.

the shared lib is located in a folder build/Release.

how to proceed to package it nicely in webpack ? or is it a particular package.json declaration ?

having a look at nodejs documentation, dll names are using extension .node
(https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_loading_addons_using_require)

webpack node-loader may help ?
https://webpack.js.org/loaders/node-loader/

I will use server side rendering , otherwise that won't be possible.

Regards,
Steph

Comment: Do you mean you want to run it inside the browser? That won't be possible.

Comment: It is possible. you have to run it server side. Very useful to access some hardware data .

Comment: That's why I asked if you want to run it in the browser, given that you tagged your question with _angular_. Even so, I don't think Webpack can bundle native addons.

Comment: Do you want to create a package for server-side using webpack?

Comment: Yes, I do. but I want being able using it in angular too. Server Side, Yes

Comment: @sancelot server-side package can't be required in front-end

Comment: Angular and Node apps should be two different apps. If you want to make use lib functionality somehow in Angular, run a web server and communicate with it via HTTP, etc (it's not even clear what's the lib and how client side can make use of it). node-loader can't help because it applies to server side apps. Similarly, it's incorrect to ask 'how to query mysql with angular', because it is server side app that does the query and it doesn't care if it's Angular or jQuery or Postman that will do requests to API.

Comment: Is you C++ library dependent upon any specific low level OS dependancies?  If geared to Windows,I'd be looking here perhaps?: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-native-loader & here https://github.com/tec27/node-native-loader

Comment: What does this have to do with TypeScript?